# css: the last line is split in two whereas it shouldn't

Tags: css

Here's my CSS:

```
div.devis-top {
  background-color:#367fb1;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  -khtml-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  -khtml-border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
}
div.devis-top div {
  padding:10px 10px 10px 20px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
div.devis-description {
  text-align:center;
}
span.devis-top-professionnels,
span.devis-top-particuliers {
  letter-spacing:-1px;
  font-weight:bold;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
span.devis-top-professionnels {
  color:#edba00;
}
span.devis-top-particuliers {
}
span.devis-top-vice-versa,
span.devis-top-slogan {
  color:#ffffff;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
span.devis-top-slogan {
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:bold;
  letter-spacing:2px;
}
img#points-de-suspension {
  vertical-align:text-top;
}
img#metiers-1 {
  float:right;
  position: relative;
  bottom:65px;
}
```

Here's the html code:

```
<body class="sbody">
  <div class="devis-top">
    <div>
      <img src="{$img_pap_devis}" alt="{$alt_img_pap_devis}" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <span class="devis-top-professionnels">De professionnels</span>
      <span class="devis-top-particuliers">à particuliers</span>
      <img id="points-de-suspension" src="{$img_points_de_suspension}" />
      <span class="devis-top-vice-versa">et vice versa</span>
      <img id="metiers-1" src="{$img_metiers_1}" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <img id="metiers-2" src="{$img_metiers_2}" />
      <span class="devis-top-slogan">comme vous voulez... quand vous voulez</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

And here's the result:

[image: CSS word wrap problem]

The last sentence should be on one line, why is it split on two lines? I don't get that. Have you any idea how to correct it?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I suspect the sentence is too long for the container, try making it shorter to confirm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to this:

```
span.devis-top-slogan {
  color:#ffffff;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  display:block;
}
```

here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rpDFL/2/

Comment: Your solution was the right one, I've add `float:right;` and a `position: relative;` to change a bit the position, I hope this will look fine in IE. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the outer element's width is wide enough to have it in just one line.

From what I can see, the `div.devis-top div` has a padding and the slogan won't fit in one line!

Change the padding (especially the right one) and it should fit.

Also, make sure the slogan stays in one line, by using the `white-space: nowrap`:

```
span.devis-top-slogan {
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:bold;
  letter-spacing:2px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Your solution makes the sentence in one line, but I wanted it to be on the right (what I didn't get is that the text in the second line **should** have fit on the right of the first line wheres the line was split).